# Forgot Password redirect to different store page after submitting email on front end

Tags: magento2, multistore, forgot-password

I have multiple store and when customer submit his email address. It redirect to another store login page. How could I redirect to the current store that the customer send his email.

Comment: When customer performs forgot password event at that time one reset password token is being generated for that customer. You will find this token within reset password link in forgot password email. You need to compare it in database. This token is saved in "rp_token" column in "customer_entity" table. You can check whether this token is generated in the same website for the same customer? I think you will get some more hint and idea from this. Let me know if you need my help further. Thanks!

Comment: I have multiple store let's say it's store A and store B. Customer that has been signed up are from Store B. And he tried to use the forgot password from store A. After that it redirect to Store B Login form. I want it to stay on Store A.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your test case properly? If your customer is signed up in store B then he should be using forgot password feature in store B only.. Why is he trying to do forgot password on store A?

Comment: I've figured it. The site got redirected from EmailNotification.php, so I tried to get the current store page ID and store it to the function.

Actually we're trying to make multisites that can be accessed by 1 registered user. So 1 user that use all the multiple store.

thank you for replying my question.